# I need to be able to make accent insensitive searches

Tags: 2sxc

I have an app for doctors search but i need to make it work for spanish searches.

I have a query but I need to make an accent insensitive search. I didn´t found an option for that in visual query editor.

Please help me with some option to achieve this kind of search.

I know can make searches directly in view with linq, but i dont know if I can save in cache search results.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct - this feature doesn't exist in visual query.

I guess someone could contribute code to make this possible, but it's probably not on anybody's priority ATM.

So I suggest you just do it with LINQ. It's usually super fast anyhow, so you probably won't miss the cache feature.

If you really need it, best contribute code ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I´m definitelly interested to contribute this and some other ideas like delete all records for an entity. Maybe you have some documentation about how to prepare environment to start working with code ?

Comment: This checklist should get you started - if something doesn't work (it could be a bit out of date) just ping me. https://azing.org/2sxc/r/D8cY_BwG